# Action button for a simple search in a view - Lotus Notes 7

Tags: search, view, action, lotus-notes

I want to create an action button to do a simple search ( based on some parameters, fields where the user can introduce what he wants to search ). I don't want to use many and many script libraries and so on ... Is there any simpliest method for this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to search a view, you can simply write the script straight into an [Action button](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_WRITING_SCRIPTS_AND_FORMULAS_FOR_ACTIONS.html&resultof=%22view%22%20%22action%22%20%22button%22%20) on the view. If you need to prompt for parameters, you can either use a [dialogbox](http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/81862484CB3919C987256AFB0012ED3D) (or look [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DIALOGBOX_METHOD.html)), which will require a form design to be created in the database, or just a series of [inputbox](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FLSAZ_INPUTBOX_FUNCTION.html&resultof=%22inputbox%22%20). Inputboxes are quite limited, but do not require additional design elements in the database, unlike a dialogbox, which requires a form, but you can do almost any kind of interface you require.

Comment: I have already have a form created in the database and also I created the Action button

Answer (score 0):

You can use form-based searching. Enable full-text search on the database, then click View/Search This View. When the search bar is open, click More (at the right). Click the Form button (the 4th), then select your search form. What forms are available as search forms is defined in the Designer, per form. See the option Include in Search Builder, in the Form Properties dialog box.